# "Cursor to Selected" Puts 3D Cursor to the World Origin Instead of Center of the Object (STL File)

Tags: 3d-printing, 3d-cursor, stl

This is an STL file I imported to Blender for 3D print. I have similar problem when dealing with most STL files (downloaded from Thingiverse and a like).

I have 3D cursor sets in the middle of selected edges like below:

[image]

If I <kbd>⇧ Shift</kbd> +  <kbd>S</kbd> then select *Cursor to Selected* while having the main model selected, the 3D cursor will be positioned like:

[image]

How can I make so that my 3D cursor positioned in the middle of the model?

Additionally, when I imported the STL file, the default position of the model is always not in the World Origin. So, that's why the model isn't positioned in the World Origin.

Answer (score 1):

You need to recalculate your object origin.
select your object and go to object > set origin and pick one you prefer.

[image]

most imported assets, export with 0 for object origin to avoid unwanted problems.

Answer (score 0):

As you can see in your first screenshot, the orange dot at the world's origin - that's the object's origin. *Cursor to Selectd* in *Object Mode* set the 3D Cursor to the object's origin (imported STL models usually have the origin at 0/0/0, no matter where the mesh is).

To set the 3D Cursor to the center of the mesh, go into *Edit Mode*, hit <kbd>A</kbd> to select all and then <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd> to set the cursor.

Or if you want the origin of the object in the center of the mesh, right-click the object in *Object Mode*, then choose *Set Origin* > *Origin to Geometry*. Other options would be *Origin to Center of Mass* for example.

After doing that, you can move the 3D Cursor to the selected object and it will be placed at the new origin. Or if you selected parts or everything of the mesh in *Edit Mode* and move the 3D Cursor there, than back in *Object Mode* you can set the object's origin to the 3D Cursor. This is helpful if you want the origin not directly in the center of an object's geometry but maybe at the bottom face or elsewhere.